# Python-Firebase How to Access Main Directory using Put and Post

Tags: firebase

I'm working with `python-firebase`. I've been trying to access the root folder, but I've been unable to do so with the `post` and `put` commands. For example, I need to do:

```
database.post (root, {"HELLO" : "HELLO"})
```

but the best I can do is two directories down. Can anyone help?

Comment: Errors? Code? Versions? Examples?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this post](http://burhan.io/flask-web-api-with-firebase/) on getting started with Firebase. The example uses a `put`.

In short, you can simply do:

```
firebase.put('/test', 'testing/tester/test', putData)
```

Each `/` defines another route down. So, in the above example, that is 3 levels down from the root. Just keep adding `/` the further you want to go.